# Angular 11 - How to export service from one module to the other

Tags: angular

In my Anular-11 project, I have core.module, auth.module, shared.module and app.module

```
core
|-config.service
core.module
```

It looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

Then the auth module

```
auth
|-register
|  |-register.component 
auth.module
```

I want to use the config.service in the core module inside the register.compoent of the auth module.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 options for how to have service accessible in your component.

1. At component level:

   ```
   @Component({
     ...
     providers: [MyService],
   })
   export class MyComponent { }
   ```

   - This way, every component instance will get its own copy of the service.
   - It will **destroy** the service upon destroying the component.

---

2. Module level:

   ```
   @NgModule({
     declarations: [
     ],
     imports: [
       CommonModule
     ],
     providers: [ConfigService]
   })
   export class CoreModule { }
   ```

   - This way the service can be lazy-loaded, ideal if the library includes heavy dependencies!
   - **The service will not ever be destroyed**! See [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37095) for more, it is a common misconception.

---

3. At root level

   ```
   @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
   export class ConfigService { }
   ```

   - Will include all its dependencies in the initial render bundle too.
   - The service will never get destroyed, maybe on navigation away, but you are not guaranteed that!

---

If you want to include a service declared in a module inside another module you have to import that module into it:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CoreModule, // <-- Here!
  ],
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

Comment: If some wants to vote to fix module not being destructed, you can do so here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37095#issuecomment-854792361

Answer (score 1):

Use the `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})` decorator on your service rather than adding it to the `providers` array in the module.

This should make your service available anywhere in your project.

[More information on Angular DI](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection)

Answer (score 1):

There are total 2 ways for achieving it 1. You need to add config.service in providers array in core.module.ts file like below

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [ConfigService]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

2. Other way is you can add `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` in your service so it can be globally accessible.

after following any of the above steps you need to inject your service in constructor of register.component like `constructor(private _configService: ConfigService) {}`